# Pairwise similarity score in a sparse matrix

Tags: python, cosine-similarity, collaborative-filtering

I am doing a CF item-based problem.

I have made a TF-idf Matrix (in pandas dataframe) that looks something like this. This is a large and extremely sparse matrix, say, 10^4 x 10^6, and each row has only 5 to 10 non-zero values.

```
|  p_Id     | 'coffee' | 'beach' | 'billiards' | ...|
|-----------|----------|---------|-------------|----|
|    "A"    |     0    |    0    | 0.3         | ...|
|    "B"    |     0.1  |    0.   | 0           | ...|
```

I want to calculate similarity score pairwise (using the cosine similarity score for example). I have two issues with my code below that I need to overcome:

1. Too slow. It takes O(N^2).
2. (MOST IMPORTANT) Similarity scores are too small that they are displayed as 0.

I look forward to your support. Thanks.

```
class SimilarityScore: 
  __id_column_name = 'p_id'
  simScore_dict = {}
  # def __pairScore(self, p1, p2, df):
  #   data1 = df[df[self.__id_column_name] == p1]
  #   data2 = df[df[self.__id_column_name] == p2]
  #   return cosine_similarity(data1, data2)

  def __pairScore(self, data1, data2):
    return cosine_similarity(data1, data2)[0][0]
  
  def calc_simScores(self,df):
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
      for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        p1 = int(df.iloc[i][self.__id_column_name])
        p2 = int(df.iloc[j][self.__id_column_name])
        data1 = df.iloc[i][1:].values.reshape(1,-1)
        data2 = df.iloc[j][1:].values.reshape(1,-1)
        # print(data1)
        simScore = self.__pairScore(data1, data2)
        if(p1 not in self.simScore_dict):
          self.simScore_dict[p1] = {}
        self.simScore_dict[p1][p2] = simScore
        if(p2 not in self.simScore_dict):
          self.simScore_dict[p2]={}
        self.simScore_dict[p2][p1] = simScore
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a similarity score for each pair, then I don't think you'll be able to reduce the O(N^2). You can speed up what you've got by using sparse matrix and caching some of the values used to calculate cosine similarity.

If you export the sparse matrix from the data frame you can then multiply it by the transpose of itself. That gives you most of the numbers you need to calculate the cosine similarity.

Something like...

```
import math
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
    
class SimilarityScore:
    __id_column_name = 'p_id'
    simScore_dict = {}

    def calc_simScores(self, df):
        # save the p_id column and drop if from the df.
        p_id_column = df.loc[:, self.__id_column_name]
        df.drop('p_id', axis=1, inplace=True)

        rows = len(df)

        # Create a sparse matrix from the df
        data = csr_matrix(df)

        matrix_products = data * data.transpose()

        # cache the lengths for each row (p_id)
        vector_lengths = {}
        for i in range(0, rows):
            # length for cosine similarity is sqrt of the vector times it's transpose.
            p_id = int(p_id_column[i])
            vector_lengths[p_id] = math.sqrt(matrix_products[i, i])

        todo = (rows*(rows-1)) // 2
        print(f'Data has {rows} rows. So, {todo} similarity scores need to be calculated.')
        done = 0
        k = 0
        for i in range(0, rows):
            p1 = int(p_id_column[i])
            for j in range(i+1, rows):
                p2 = int(p_id_column[j])

                # calculate cosine similarity
                vector_product = matrix_products[i, j]
                similarity_score = 0
                if vector_product != 0:
                    p1_length = vector_lengths[p1]
                    p2_length = vector_lengths[p2]
                    similarity_score = vector_product / (p1_length * p2_length)

                if p1 not in self.simScore_dict:
                    self.simScore_dict[p1] = {}
                self.simScore_dict[p1][p2] = similarity_score

                if p2 not in self.simScore_dict:
                    self.simScore_dict[p2] = {}
                self.simScore_dict[p2][p1] = similarity_score

                # simple progress indicator
                k += 1
                if k >= 50000:
                    done += k
                    k = 0
                    print(f'Done {done} out of {todo}.')

        print(f'Finished. Total calculations = {done+k}')
```

And a test - based on what you posted, but I've assumed p_id has numeric values:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
tf_idf_data = StringIO("""p_id|coffee|beach|billiards
    0    |     0    |    0    | 0.3
    1    |     0.1  |    0.   | 0
    2    |     0.1  |    0.   | 0.2
    3    |     0    |    0.   | 0.2
  """)
df = pd.read_csv(tf_idf_data, delimiter='|')

sim_score = SimilarityScore()
sim_score.calc_simScores(df)

print(sim_score.simScore_dict)
```